# 1-1 correspondence between $\text{Hom}_k (U,V)$ to set of all $m \times n$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

$\text{Hom}_k (U,V)$ represents the set of all linear maps from $U \rightarrow V$. $U$ and $V$ are finite dimensional.

How would I define the correspondence between this set and the set $K^{m,n}$ of all $m \times n$ matrices over $K$?

Comment: My guess is that you forgot something about the dimensions of $U$ and $V$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes they are finite dimensional.

Comment: More specifically, $\dim U=n$ and $\dim V=m$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pick bases $\{u_1,\cdots,u_n\}$ for $U$ and $\{v_1,\cdots,v_m\}$ for $V$.

The matrix $A=[a_{ij}]$ defines a linear transformation $T_A:U\to V$ by $f(u_i)=\sum_j a_{ij}v_j$. This gives us $f(u)$ for all $u\in U$ by "extending linearly";

$$ f(c_1u_1+\cdots+c_nu_n)=c_1f(u_1)+\cdots+c_nf(u_n).$$

This gives a map $K^{m,n}\to \hom(U,V)$. Conversely, given a linear transformation $T:U\to V$, we can evaluate it at each basis vector $u_i$ and decompose each $f(u_i)\in V$ using the basis for $V$ say as $f(u_i)=\sum_j a_{ij}v_j$, which determines a matrix $[a_{ij}]$. This provides a map $\hom(U,V)\to K^{m,n}$ inverse to the other one.

Comment: This has proved that there is a correspondence. But I don't see how it has 'defined' the correspondence?

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove Given a matrix $A\in K^{m,n}$, we get a **corresponding** linear map $T_A\in\hom(U,V)$. And given a linear map $T\in\hom(U,V)$, we get a **corresponding** matrix in $K^{m,n}$. So, yes, I've just defined a **correspondence** between $K^{m,n}$ and $\hom(U,V)$. Indeed, representing linear maps with respect to bases is the *whole point* behind matrices in the first place!

Comment: How could I show this correspondence is a linear map?

Comment: The scalar multiplication and addition in $\hom(U,V)$ is pointwise scalar multiplication and addition of functions. So, what does it *mean* for this correspondence to be linear? It means, for all scalars $c$, matrices $A$, and column vectors $u,v$ that $(cA)v=c(Av)$ and $A(v+w)=Av+Aw$. Which is true.